# JQuery detect changes made within an iFrames body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Basically,

I have a WYSIWYG Editor that hides the textarea from within the form and replaces is with a `contenteditable=true` iframe. I'm trying to detect the changes to the contents within the iframe for my auto update function i've created. It currently works with normal input fields such as input & select however i'd like it to detect when the contents changes within the iframe.

This is what i have at the moment but nothing happens:

```
$("iframe.cke_wysiwyg_frame").contents().find('body').on("change", function() {
  // execute function for auto update
});
```

I've tried on keyup & input too but nothing happens when the content within the iframe changes. For testing purposes i'm trying to `alert("it works");` within but nothing happens.

Is there a way that i can target the changes inside the editable iframe? (note: the iframe is within the document it's not external)

Thanks

EDIT: iframe structure
[image]

Comment: Can you post the `iframe` and what's inside? It'd be hard to answer without seeing the structure.

Comment: When do you bind this event? Before or after the iframe has been created? Before you bind an event, you should debug and make sure `$("iframe.cke_wysiwyg_frame").contents().find('body')` finds an element

Comment: body has no change event, try keyup

Comment: $("iframe.cke_wysiwyg_frame").contents().find('body') this does find it because my auto update function works with this when it updates every 30 seconds it inserts into the database the contents of the body e.g: <p>Hi</p> would insert in through the auto update function. But i want it so that when i change that Hi to say Hi How're you, each keypress will trigger the auto update function. At the moment with the code provided nothing happens, but the feature every 30 seconds would do it.

Comment: keyup doesn't do anything either

Comment: create a demo in jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/86dn48c2/ That works, however i'm trying to do it to simply alert when you type however, with the structure i've shown above and the code i've provided even if i change the selector to be 'iframe' without the class it doesn't work. The JQuery is placed AFTER the iframe and i've also got it right at the end of the document and that does nothing :/

Comment: The WYSIWYG editor that the iframe is apart of is from CKE Editor

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the WYSIWYG Editor i was using was the issue, and that you can get instances from CKEditor with a plug-in from:

http://alfonsoml.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/onchange-event-for-ckeditor.html